# How to getting parent node of XPath query result in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I use javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder in the java.
Given markup like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <calendar>
        <endfiscalyear month="12" dayofmonth="28" />
        <year yr="2014">
          <event month="12" dayofmonth="24">
            <p>Dividendenauszahlung</p>
            <en>dividend payment</en>
          </event>
        </year>
        <year yr="2015">
          <event month="2" dayofmonth="1">
            <p>Hauptversammlung</p>
            <en>general meeting</en>
          </event>
           <event month="5" dayofmonth="2">
            <p>Hauptversammlung</p>
            <en>general meeting</en>
          </event>
          <event month="8" dayofmonth="21">
            <p>Ergebnis 2.Quartal</p>
            <en>1st quarter results</en>
          </event>
        </year>
      </calendar>
```

Now I am interested in getting the last year and month and dayofmonth only, where the last is 'general meeting', in this mask it should be year@yr=2015, `<event month="4" dayofmonth="21">`. I can get the year, month and day separately, but as i tried, none of them get shown. 
first l'd like any year: the two ways that i tried are:

```
//*@yr[event/en='general meeting']
```

or

```
/calendar/year[event/en='general meeting']@yr
```

but none of them are correct. 
How would you like to solve the problem?

Comment: You just need to step back by `../../@yr`

Comment: @KennethClark What expression are you talking about?

Comment: great, the expression "/calendar/year[event/en='general meeting']/@yr" works. Thank you. And the next step i will get the "larger" year of the "general meeting". Above there are year 2014 and year 2015. 2015 >2014, then i get 2015. I think it should be "/calendar/year[last()][event/en='general meeting']/@yr". But how can i get the year, month and day together?

Comment: Jipeng, I will not be notified if you do not either comment on my answer, or ping me with @. No, in your input document, there is no year with a general meeting inside it and where `yr` is equal to "2015".

Comment: @Mathias Müller Sorry, i am new here, had bad manner:) I just want make a example, and have forgotten, that i have delete the "general meeting" in 2015. Something new: as i tried to get the last month that has "general meeting", the expression "/calendar/year/event[p='Hauptversammlung'][last()]/@dayofmonth" did not gave me the right answer, why?

Comment: Jipeng, I understand you are new here; so let me explain the basics. On Stackoverflow, people do not mention "something new" in comments - instead, please **edit** your question if you'd actually like to ask about something different. Also, I am really confused because you commented on my answer, saying that it is what you were looking for - whereas your comment here suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are asking, but sometimes it is easier to comment on an attempted solution than trying to explain.

The following XPath expression is valid:

```
/calendar/year[event/en='general meeting']/@yr
```

and here is what it does:

> Select `year` elements, but only if they have a child element `event`, which in turn has a child element `en`, whose textual content is "general meeting". Of those `year` elements select the attribute `yr`.

For the input document you show, only one such attribute would qualify, and therefore the output would be

```
 yr="2015"
```

Is this what you had in mind? If not, please *show* (instead of trying to explain) the output you expect from an expression - and explain *why* this result should be selected.

Comment: yes, that is the answer that i want! great! I had forgotten that the "/" must lay before @. Thank you.